# Ext JS Tree with Grid in nodes - combine widgets

Tags: javascript, gridview, treeview, extjs, widget

I'm looking for a solution on how to combine two widgets. I'm taling about the Tree widget and the Grid widget in such way that f.e. every node of tree represents a database table and after expanding it shows record in a grid widget. Is there a way to combine those two in one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, TreeGrid didn't work particularly well with some flexible layouts and always had to have a fixed width (probably they changed this in the latest versions, my last experience was with 2.2). For similar tasks I used nested grids and row expanders. Here is one of possible implementations
http://mikhailstadnik.com/ext/examples/nested-grid.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TreeGrid.  Example here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html